# Route not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I 'think' I have successfully installed Laravel using 2 different internet guides. Here is one one of them

http://phpraxis.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/getting-started-with-laravel-4-on-ubuntu-installation-and-configuration/

I have managed to get the include laravel test page "You have arrived"

I am now unable to add an additional route. This is what I did in the routes.php file

|

```
*/

Route::get('/', function()
{
        return View::make('hello');
});


Route::any('foo', function()
{
    return 'Hello Andrea';
});
```

If I add a page foo or foo.php I get the error

Not Found

The requested URL /foo was not found on this server.

I can alter the code in the default view

However if I do something like this

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
        return 'Hello Andrea';
});
```

everything is fine

I'm confused. I don't think I get Laravel views. how would I fix this to work as a first step on my jourmey

```
Route::any('foo', function()
{
    return 'Hello Andrea';
});
```

Some guides also suggested putting Laravel in the home folder e.g. /home/username/laravel and whan I tried this I couldnt even get the 'you have arrived page'

I thought Laravel had a shallow learning curve? It must be me.

Thanks for any help

## Edit

Ihave found a page that says that conf.d in the PHP file is the old way and it should only be on the other directories on the same level~: apach2 and cli, and now you make the sym link in apache2 and cli. Any opinions much appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: where are you adding the 'foo.php' file? You shouldn't have to add any view file to get that simple route to work. try just removing the file you added and then visiting that route.  if you are trying to set up a blade template file, the file should be named `foo.blade.php` and should be saved somewhere in the `app/views` folder

Comment: The url for render "hello" view, works fine?

Comment: ~watcher = it was just a grab all trying to go to any page with foo in

Comment: ~soldier = yes it works finr

Comment: You should accept the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have mod_rewrite for Apache on and you have in your `public` folder the following `.htaccess` file (Laravel defaults):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I ddnt have to do anything wth the mod rewrite.

Comment: I wrote an apache site configuration file

Answer (score 0):

go to the httpd.conf file of the server and remove hash from line showing below

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```